# PostgreSQL 9.5: Return matching search terms in each result row when using LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query which joins two tables and returns items that match the given search strings as a prefix (In this example the search strings are "apple", "banana", and "orange" but they could be anything and there could be one or more of them).  The search strings will always be treated as a prefix (i.e., will have a trailing '%' but no leading '%')

```
SELECT
  orders.orderid,
  orders.order_name,
  fields.item_name
FROM public.workorder_fields AS fields 
LEFT JOIN public.workorder AS orders 
ON fields.orderid = orders.orderid
WHERE fields.item_name LIKE 'apple%'
      OR fields.item_name LIKE 'banana%'
      OR fields.item_name LIKE 'orange%';
```

The query works great and returns what I expect which is a list of results that look something like this:

```
-- Current Query Results

1   "order 1"   "apple pie"
2   "order 2"   "apple juice"
5   "order 5"   "orange juice"
10  "order 10"  "banana split"
```

What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to also return for each result row the search string that matched.  For example, I would like the above results to look like this:

```
-- Desired Query Results

1   "order 1"   "apple pie"     "apple"
2   "order 2"   "apple juice"   "apple"
5   "order 5"   "orange juice"  "orange"
10  "order 10"  "banana split"  "banana"
```

> Note the fourth column which shows the search term that led to the row being considered a match.

Is there anyway to modify the original query to be able to return the search string that was used to find the match for each row in the results?

I wasn't quite sure how to describe the issue I'm trying to solve so apologies in advance if this should have been described differently or is well asked/solved already here on stackoverflow.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: As well as the CASE answer, you could also turn your query into a series of UNION ALL statements, each one having a single filter (`item_name like 'orange%'` etc), and add a column with a constant value, as in `'orange' as match_value`). You'd need to test the execution timing against your data sets, but it is another option.

Comment: Thank you for the UNION ALL suggestion.  The "case" suggestion seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CASE` may do the job

```
SELECT
  orders.orderid,
  orders.order_name,
  fields.item_name,
  CASE WHEN fields.item_name LIKE 'apple%' THEN 'apple'
       WHEN fields.item_name LIKE 'banana%' THEN 'banana'
       WHEN fields.item_name LIKE 'orange%' THEN 'orange'
  END as match
FROM public.workorder_fields AS fields 
LEFT JOIN public.workorder AS orders 
ON fields.orderid = orders.orderid
WHERE fields.item_name LIKE 'apple%'
      OR fields.item_name LIKE 'banana%'
      OR fields.item_name LIKE 'orange%';
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Worked out well.