# Postgresql Query - Return all matching search terms for each result row when using an ANY query and LIKE

Tags: postgresql

Essentially what I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to return all matching search terms in addition to the matched row when running a query that looks up a list of items using `ANY` or `IN`.  In most cases the search term will exactly match the returned column value but in cases such as text search or with certain extensions like IP4r this is not always the case.  In addition, you can have multiple search terms match on a single row.

To make this concrete suppose this is my query:

```
SELECT id, item_name, description FROM items WHERE description LIKE ANY('{%gaming%, %computer%, %socks%, %men%}');
```

and it returns the following two rows:

```
id, item_name, description
1, 'computer', 'super fast gaming computer that will help you win'
5, 'socks', 'These socks are sure to please the men in your family'
```

What I'd like to know is which original search terms map to the result row that was returned.  In other words, I'd like the returned rows to look like this:

```
id, search_terms, item_name, description
1, '{%gaming%, %computer%}', 'computer', 'super fast gaming computer that will help you win'
5, '{%socks%, %men%}', 'socks', 'These socks are sure to please the men in your family'
```

Is there a way to efficiently do this in PostgreSQL?  In the example above we're using LIKE with strings but in my real-world scenario I'm using the IP4r extension to do IP lookups against CIDR ranges where you can have multiple IP addresses in the same returned CIDR range.

I previously asked this question: [PostgreSQL 9.5: Return matching search terms in each result row when using LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036575/postgresql-9-5-return-matching-search-terms-in-each-result-row-when-using-like) which used a CASE statement to almost solve the problem I'm describing here.

The added complexity in the scenario above is that you can have multiple search terms match a single row (e.f., `gaming` and `computer` are both matches for the description `super fast gaming computer that will help you win`).  If you use a CASE statement then only the first match in the CASE statement gets set as the search term and you miss any other matching search terms.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a way using `VALUES`:

```
SELECT i.id, i.item_name, i.description, m.pat
FROM items AS i
   JOIN (VALUES ('%gaming%'), ('%computer%'), ('%socks%'), ('%men%')) AS m(pat)
      ON i.description LIKE m.pat;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is returning a row per match which definitely works.  Is there an efficient way to group the `m.pat` fields into an array (single row), or would that be more efficient to do in the application layer?

Comment: You can use `array_agg` to turn a set of rows into an array and `unnest` for the other way around. So it doesn't matter much which format you choose.